# struct name* ошибка

Tags: c, строки, struct, malloc, calloc

У меня такой вопрос. У меня есть структура, которую нужно заполнить соответствующими данными, полученными из мною написанной функции. Вроде все сделал правильно, но при попытке вывода пишет Segmentation Fault.
P.S. все типы данных должны быть в том виде, в котором они заданны (не могу const char* изменить на char* и тд)

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test {
    char* name; 
    int age;  
};

struct test* create_track(const char* name, int age) {
    if(name == "" || strlen(name) > 100) {
        return NULL;
    }
    struct test* new_test = (struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    strcpy(new_test->name, name);
    new_test->age = age;
    return new_test;
}

int main() {
    struct test* track = create_track("John", 26);
    printf("%s %d\n", track->name, track->age);
}
```

Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, проверять `name == ""` бессмысленно - потому что такое сравнение сравнивает *указатель* `name` c указателем на строку `""` - с очевидным результатом: они не равны. C-строки нужно сравнивать с помощью функций типа `strcmp`.

После выделения памяти

```
struct test* new_test = (struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

вы копируете строку

```
strcpy(new_test->name, name);
```

куда? Вы никак не инициализировали выделенную память, так сто в поле `name` какое-то левое значение, адрес памяти *где-то*, куда вы пытаетесь писать.

Нужно выделить память и для строки, куда планируете копировать - типа

```
new_test->name = malloc(....);
```

Да, и еще - если вы действительно компилируете код как C, а не как С++ - то можете опустить приведения типов перед вызовами `malloc`. Они необходимы в C++.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромезное!! Это правда сработало. У  меня после этого исправления еще появился маленький вопрос. Если Я делаю проверки на NULL (те, что в моем коде(то что Вы говорили, я исправил)), то мне выбивает SegFault. Могли бы Вы мне пожалуйста еще подсказать почему так?

Comment: Покажите, **как** вы их делаете...

Comment: `int main() {
    struct test* track = create_track("", 26);
    printf("%s %d\n", track->name, track->age);
}`
P.S. это при том же коде, только с Вашими исправлениями

Comment: Здесь нет проверки на NULL. Но если вы проверяете `strcmp(name,"")` - то получаете `track == NULL`, который потом разыменовываете (track->name, track->age) - т.е. причина сбоя очевидно - попытка обращения к памяти по указателю NULL.

Comment: Да, я именно такую проверку и хотел сделать. А как тогда можно при `strcmp(name,"")` выводить NULL, а не `SEGFAULT`?

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я бы хотел, чтобы если у меня `name` было больше чем на 100 символов, или если оно вообще пустое `""`, то мне выводилось `NULL`, но мне выводится `SegFault`. Вы не знаете случайно как  бы можно было нормально вывести `NULL`?

Comment: Вам не "выводится SegFault". Вы получаете от функции адрес NULL, который нельзя читать-писать - это UB. Вы дальше пытаетесь вывести `target->name`. Что это значит? Что вы пытаетесь прочесть, что там лежит в памяти по этому адресу? А этого делать НЕЛЬЗЯ! SegFault - это не ваш `printf` выводит, это программа аварийно останавливается.

Comment: Все, я понял! Огромезное Вам спасибо!)